# CSS - body 100% with two divs, one with 100% height and second is fixed height

Tags: html, css

I want #main to be 100%, but not affected by #upper -- pushed down by 39px and making the page scrollable. Overflow: hidden on body won't do it for me, since I need to see content at the bottom. How do I fix this? Something similar to sticky footer, or? I don't seem to understand it.

```
<body>
<div id="upper"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="box"></div>    
</div>
</body>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#upper {
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #212121;
}
#main {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;    
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
```

Picture of how it looks http://i46.tinypic.com/25k1jcn.jpg

Comment: Can you please post a sketch of the results you want?  It's a lot easier than trying to describe it.  Also, here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se3mu/) using the code you provided.

Comment: Is there any specific browser compatibility you need?

Comment: @SurrealDreams I added image to the question: http://i46.tinypic.com/25k1jcn.jpg Yep, same happens in jsFiddle, it adds that annoying scroll.

Comment: one way is set position: absolute; to #upper if you are using elements same as you writed here its good way.

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt the [stickyfooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) method to become a stickyheader?

Comment: @perdickss dont want to hide any content behind #upper, I have background image, thats why.

Comment: Could you not have 39px of blank area in your background image designed to be covered?

Comment: @SurrealDreams thats not an option for me, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to @Zoltan's answer:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#upper {
  height: 39px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #212121;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;    
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 39px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="upper"></div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="box">Hi</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: There ya go, looks like your code now. You don't even need to set top and left... http://jsfiddle.net/NWKxs/2/

Comment: No prob, keep in mind I do no think my solution is 100% cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ax7nq/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#upper {
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #212121;
    position: absolute;
}
#main {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;    
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightblue;
}

#box {
    padding-top: 39px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing #upper to this:

```
#upper
{
    height: 39px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #212121;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```